# Finding an element using placeholder in Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, testing, protractor, placeholder

```
<input _ngcontent-c6="" formcontrolname="password" 
    name="password" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Password'" 
    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
    placeholder="Password" 
    required="" type="password" 
    ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-name="password" 
    class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
```

What is the best way to find an element: `placeholder = "Enter Username"`?

**Scenario:** find an element using Snippet above User clicks on the `"Enter Name"` box, another window pops-up for entering a name.

Comment: css selector:  `input[placeholder="Password"]`

Comment: HTML refers to `placeholder="Password"`, question speaks of `placeholder = "Enter Username"` and in scenario you spoke of `"Enter Name"`. What is your exact _usecase_?

Answer (score 4):

For placeholder you can use:

```
element(by.css('[placeholder = "Password"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath like this:

```
.//input[@placeholder='Enter Username']
```